# No Generated Types from WSDL only Methods in WCF 4.5

Tags: wcf

After creating a service, I tried to add it as a reference in another project.  I did that and it created the client but I only see the methods of my service, not custom types that it should be generating.

For example, I added a service reference such as `http://ourdomain.com/Payment.svc`

should I be referencing `http://ourdomain.com/Payment.svc?wsdl` or `?singlewsdl` as the service reference url?

Note that if I add the service reference via http://ourdomain.com/Payment.svc?singlewsdl It doesn't generate a client but I can see the types in the Reference.cs created.

Comment: In what project are the types defined.  Ar the data contracts defined in the server project or a separate project?

Comment: Are these types used as parameters or return values from the service operations? These are the only types that would be described in the WSDL. Do you see these types in the WSDL/XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options `?wsdl` and `?singlewsdl` will product an equivalent service description WSDL document. The difference is that `?wsdl` separates the "type" (classes in C#) definition into multiple XSD files and `?singlewsdl` produces a single file containing the service description and XSD definitions. In Visual Studio, it makes no difference which option you use. If you're using SvcUtil (or another platform tool) then it's much easier to work with a single file to generate a proxy. Actually, some older tools require a single file.

Your "problem" may be actually a code generation feature. Open the service reference configuration dialog (right click on it and select 'configure service') for your service. You'll see an option that is usually on by default: *Reuse types in referenced assemblies*. The *Reuse types in all referenced assemblies* is likely also checked. These selections will **prevent** a Reference.cs file from containing any types if they are already referenced in another assembly. Generally you should leave these checked. To control this when you create the service reference, click the Advanced button (bottom left) in the add service reference dialog to see the configuration options.